# scale numbers (more than 2 digits) removed on insertion

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I defined a table column like this:

```
Column name: Lat
DataType: decimal(9,6)
```

And my model definition:

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:000.000000}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
    public decimal Lat { get; set; }
```

[As I mentioned above I changed column manually to decimal(9,6)]
I use EF6 to create new record in database. 
When I want to insert value **35.6997311** for `Lat` the result in database is **35.690000** (4 digits converted to zero).

Why EF remove digits and insert zero instead of them? and how can I insert full number in database?

My controller action for insertion:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Lat,CreatedAt")] Example example)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Agencies.Add(example);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(example);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an attribute to scale the digits.

Create a `DecimalPrecision` attribute like this;

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DecimalPrecision : Attribute
{
    public byte precision { get; set; }
    public byte scale { get; set; }
    public DecimalPrecision(byte precision, byte scale)
    {
        this.precision = precision;
        this.scale = scale;
    }
    public static void ConfigureModelBuilder(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Properties().Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<DecimalPrecision>().Any())
            .Configure(c => c.HasPrecision(c.ClrPropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<DecimalPrecision>().First()
                .precision, c.ClrPropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<DecimalPrecision>().First().scale));
    }
}
```

Then inside your Context `OnModelBuilder` function, call the `DecimalPrecision.ConfigureModelBuilder()` method

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    DecimalPrecision.ConfigureModelBuilder(modelBuilder);
}
```

**Usage;**

Add `DecimalPrecision` attribute on the property;

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:000.000000}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
[DecimalPrecision(9,6)]
public decimal Lat { get; set; }
```

Comment: +1.  Was just typing up the same thing.  Entity Framework has a default decimal precision of (18,2).  You're casting your c# decimal into an 18,2 - which cuts off all but the first two decimals - and then displaying it as #.######, which gives you a final product of #.##000000.

Comment: But I get this error: `the type or namespace name DecimalPrecisionAttribute could not be found...` @Kevin @Rainman

Comment: "db.Agencies.Add(example)" db is your context. Find the context class and if OnModelCreating doesn't exist, override it as I explained.